# Set startup screen to *About GNU Emacs* page

Tags: start-up

When I start Emacs, it shows me the *GNU Emacs* buffer. I want to set it to the page one gets with the `C-h C-a` command with the nice Emacs logo instead. How can I do this.

Answer (score 2):

Place this one-liner somewhere in your `.emacs` or `init.el` file:

```
(setq initial-buffer-choice 'about-emacs)
```