# Launch emacs in eww mode, display local .html file at startup

Tags: init-file, start-up, html, eww

I'm new to Emacs and I'm going about customizing my install on Mac OS Catalina.

I have a twist on a common request.

I had the idea to customize the **emacs startup screen**, but I see those options are limited based on what I've read so far. You can switch out the logo, maybe change the bg color, customize the text string associated with that screen, but you can't really dig into it per say because it's all in the source code.

So I got the idea of **displaying a local html file** (or one on a LAN) instead. I got that to display on launch, but it's showing in HTML code mode/buffer. I found this line for my .emacs file [elsewhere](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/39110/set-startup-screen-to-about-gnu-emacs-page): `(setq initial-buffer-choice "~/.emacs.d/startup.html")`

My question is... **Is there a way to launch Emacs in eww browser mode and display a local `startup.html` file?** *(Which is like hitting a nail with a sledgehammer I know but, I was curious.)*

Related to this, can you specify a handler for links to files within a page displayed by eww? (e.g. .mp4,.mp3, html, pdf,.csv, etc.)

Comment: This dashboard package (https://github.com/emacs-dashboard/emacs-dashboard) has a lot of promise. It might be good enough for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in $HOME/.emacs.d/init.el and start up emacs:

```
(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)
(eww-open-file "/path/to/startup.html")
```

If you want to visit a URL instead, just replace the second line with

```
(eww "https://example.com/index.html")
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: screenshot please

Comment: As requested. Here's a [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/0gmz1YY.jpg). As you can see emacs launches with eww browser open in eww mode, showing a local page in my user folder called sandwich.html The page is very simple for now, just showing a large logo.